# passing pointers

Tags: c++11

I have this declared above:

```
char PandaImage[] = "images/panda.png";
SDL_Texture* PandaTexture = nullptr;
```

I have a function to create textures:

```
void LoadMedia( SDL_Texture *ThisTexture, char *Image )        
{
   SDL_Surface* TempSurface = nullptr;
  .......................

  ThisTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, TempSurface );
```

I call it as:

```
  LoadMedia( PandaTexture, PandaImage );
```

It builds, logs the image loaded and texture created, but no image
If I hard change the line ( use Panda directly instead of This ):

```
PandaTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, TempSurface );
```

My image is there.
I have always had trouble with & * and passing. 
Is there a good, simple help for me?
Thanks for your kind help - back to Google for now

Comment: The address stored in the pointer is being copied, you want to pass a reference to the pointer as you suggested :)

Comment: Better yet, return the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In short, I think you could solve your problem by changing the function to:

```
void LoadMedia( SDL_Texture** thisTexture, char* Image) 
{ 
    ...
    (*thisTexture) = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, TempSurface);
}
```

And by calling the function using:

```
LoadMedia( &PandaTexture, PandaImage);
```

An explanation:

---

## Variables and Pointers

A **variable** is used to store **data** (a primitive or a class instance). For example:

```
int a = 10;
```

stores an integer in memory. This means, that symbol *'a'* now represents number 10, which is stored somewhere in your computer's memory as 4 bytes.

A **pointer** is used to store an **address** (this address points towards a variable). For example:

```
int* a_address = 1234;
```

says that there is an integer stored at address 1234 in your computer's memory. A pointer always takes up the same amount of space (4 bytes on a 32 bit machine and 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine), as it simply stores an address.

---

## Getting the Address of a Variable [&]

You will rarely ever set the address of a pointer yourself. Often, pointers are the result of a **"new" call**. Using "new" reserves memory to store an instance of the class you want to create, and returns the address of the object. In essence, it says: "I created an object for you, and you can find it at this location in your memory".

Alternatively, when you have a normal **variable** (primitive of class instance), you can **find its address** by using the *&* character. For example:

```
int a = 10;
int* a_address = &a;
```

says: "store the location of variable *a* in pointer *a_address*. Why would you do this? Say you have a very large instance (for example an *SDL_Texture* consisting of many, many pixels) and you want to pass it to a function (or pass it back outside of the function). If you were to pass it to the function as *SDL_Texture thisTexture*, you are copying the entire object (a so-called **pass by value**). This is time consuming. Alternatively, you could simply pass the address to the function, as an *SDL_Texture* * *thisTexture*. This is a so called **pass by reference**, and it is much faster as you can imagine.

---

## Getting the Variable at an Address [*]

Obviously, if you have an address, you also need a way to **get the actual variable** at that address. This is done using the * character. It is called **"dereferencing"**. For example:

```
int a = 10;
int* a_address = &a;
int b = (*a_address);
```

This last line says: "Give me the variable, stored at address a_address, and put it in b".

---

## Function Parameters Going Out-of-scope

When a function ends, its local variables (including parameters) go **out-of-scope**. This means that their memory is freed (for variables, not for dynamically allocated objects stored as pointers!). Their values will be forgotten. In your case, you are passing an *SDL_Texture* * as a parameter. This means, a copy is made of the address stored in *PandaTexture*. This address is copied over to *thisTexture*. You then write the return value of *SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface* to *thisTexture*. Next the function ends, and *thisTexture* goes out-of-scope. As a result, the location of your *SDL_Texture* (the *SDL_Texture* * pointer) is lost forever. You actually want to store the address to pointer *PandaTexture*, but as you can see, the address is only written to *thisTexture*.

## Solution: How to Fix your Function

We can fix this by passing a pointer, to your pointer called *PandaTexture*. A "pointer to a pointer" is written as:

```
SDL_Surface** thisTexture;
```

We want to pass the **address of pointer PandaTexture** to this. This way, we can write to *PandaTexture* from inside your method! After all, we know where *PandaTexture* stores its pointer in memory, allowing us to change it. To actually put the address of *PandaTexture* in it, we need to use the & character in the function call as such:

```
LoadMedia(&PandaTexture, PandaImage);
```

Next, inside of our function, we want to change the value of PandaTexture. However, we were passed *&PandaTexture* and not PandaTexture itself. To write the value of &PandaTexture (the address where our texture will be stored), we need dereferencing, as such:

```
(*thisTexture) = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, TempSurface);
```

This works because: "*thisTexture* is a pointer to a pointer to an *SDL_Texture* (aka an SDL_Texture**). By dereferencing it, we obtain a pointer to an *SDL_Texture* (aka an SDL_Texture*). Here we can store the return value of the *SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface* function.

Why do we not run into out-of-scope issues here? Parameter *thisTexture* will still go out of scope, and its value will be forgotten. But! We didn't write to *thisTexture*, instead we wrote our *SDL_Texture* * pointer to the address that *thisTexture* points to! This bit of memory is not cleared due to scoping, so we can view the results from outside the function!

---

In summary, you can solve your problem using a pointer to a pointer. I hope the above clears up the concepts of pointers, variables, addresses and dereferencing a bit!